# os.path.getmtime of shared files in Dropbox

Tags: python, dropbox

I want to run a script to check whether certain files in my Dropbox folder have changed. I am currently using os.path.getmtime() to check that the modified time is in some window of time.time(). The problem is that if I modify a file in my Dropbox folder from a different computer than where the script is set to run, the modified time does not change on that latter computer. Is there a good way to watch shared files that doesn't run into this problem?

Thanks for any help! I am just getting into python.

*******UPDATE*******

I have been playing more with how Dropbox handles file timestamping. It only updates the mtime if the file changes. If you open a file, modify it, but save it unchanged, the mtime stays the same.

Comment: How do you save it unchanged?

Answer (score 1):

It looks that Dropbox preserves mtime when synchronizing files. Try to detect changed file by changed file size and/or checksum (MD5, SHA1 or so) instead of modification time. Or just ask Dropbox :) (I don't know if it has any API for this).